# Variable inside variable?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I created a batch file that searches for the users desktop folder in Windows.

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=3* delims= " %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop') do set DESKTOP=%%a
```

If my desktop folder isn't in `C:\Users\User\Desktop`, it will work and return the correct folder, for example in my case `E:\User\Desktop`. If the desktop folder is in `C:\Users\User\Desktop`, the script above will result into `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`. Later in the script I try to create a new file on desktop. In the first option it will work, because `E:\User\Desktop` is a real directory. In the second one it won't because obviously `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` doesn't count as a directory.

```
echo start javaw -jar "path/to/program.jar" >"%DESKTOP%\Start program.bat"
```

How to get it work on both situations?

Doing

```
if /I "%DESKTOP%" EQU "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
```

doesn't help because it is the same as

```
if /I "%DESKTOP%" EQU "C:\Users\User\Desktop"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `call` to expand the variable:
`call set desktop=%desktop%`

Comment: +1; I was going to provide an expanded version of that answer when I was asked to make breakfast for the family. LOL

Answer (score 2):

You need an extra round of normal expansion. As wmz has already answered, you can get that extra round by using CALL.

You should be careful about special characters like `&` or `^` that are valid in folder and file names. I recommend using quotes in your assignment to protect special characters.

```
call set "DESKTOP=%DESKTOP%"
```

I am assuming the value of DESKTOP does not already include quotes. All bets are off if you have a mixture of definitions that sometimes include quotes, and other times don't.

Suppose `DESKTOP=This & that\%VAR%` and `VAR=& the other thing`. The end result with the quoted assignment using CALL will be correct: `This & that\& the other thing`.

I have seen `&` in folder names in the real world, so the quotes are a good thing. However, there is a problem if your value contains `^`. A quoted `^` is doubled if passed through CALL.

Suppose `DESKTOP=one^two%var%` and `VAR=^three`, the end result of the quoted assignment using CALL will be `one^^two^three`.

I don't think I have ever run across `^` in a folder name, but it is possible, and there is a solution. You can use CMD /C to get another round of expansion, and use FOR /F to capture the result.

The following will give the correct result of `one^two^three`. I use `"eol=:"` because a valid path can never begin with `:`.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%B in ('cmd /c echo "%DESKTOP%"') do set "DESKTOP=%%~B"
```

You do not need to use an intermediate assignment of DESKTOP. In all of the above, you can substitute your FOR /F `%%a` in place of `%DESKTOP%`.